# Exporting photo to Screenshots doesn't add the photo to the Gallery

Tags: android, kotlin, android-image, android-gallery, android-camera-intent

My intention is to generate an image and that the user can see it later in the gallery of their mobile phone.

For this I use the following code:

```
private fun saveToInternalStorage(bitmap: Bitmap) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            saveBitmapAndroidQ(bitmap)
        } else {
            val imagesDir =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "Screenshots")
                    .toString()
            val image = File(imagesDir, "AppName_${UUID.randomUUID()}.jpg")
            val fos = FileOutputStream(image)

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            Objects.requireNonNull(fos).close();
            Log.d("exportation", "imagesDir: " + image.toString())
        }
    }
```

The image is stored in the following URI (and I have checked it manually observing that it is there in the internal storage of my mobile phone):

`/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/AppName_113a5010-fbef-41da-b4cc-88f94e25740e.jpg`

However, when I open my Gallery App it does not appear anywhere, neither looking for it by name, nor in the "Screenshots" folder, etc. All Screenshots appear except this new image that I have generated with the App.

**How can I make the Gallery display my image?**

On the other hand, I would like to be able to create a directory within Pictures that has the name of my App, something like:

`/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyAppFolder/`

To store images (and have them appear in the gallery), **how can I create my own directory?**

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you reboot your device it will be in the 'gallery' after some time.

Comment: You can use File.mkdirs() to create a subdidectory in Pictures.

Comment: If you want your picture to be visible in 'the gallery' right away you have to statr the media scanner for your file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you blackapps for guiding me on what to use, this is what I missed:

**Manifest**

```
<manifest [...]>

[...]

    <!-- Refresh Media -->
    <protected-broadcast android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />

    <application [...]

        <activity [...]

            <!-- Refresh Media  -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
</manifest>
```

**Fragment**

```
    private fun addGallery(file: File) {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(requireContext(), 
            arrayOf<String>(file.getAbsolutePath()),
            arrayOf("image/jpeg"),
            object : MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener {
                override fun onScanCompleted(path: String?, uri: Uri?) {
                    // Blank
                }
            })
    }
```